# Beamer Metropolis Colors

Tags: beamer, color, beamer-metropolis

In the beamer metropolis package one is capable to highlight text using the `\alert{}` command in orange. Further it is possible to create a block, where the header is in the same color `\begin{alertblock} --- \end{alertblock}`.

My question now is, if it is possible to use the color of `\begin{exampleblock} --- \end{exampleblock}` to highlight text in green?. Either I don't find it using the documentation or it is really not possible. If so, how can I select the color using for example the `\usepackage{color}` and the respective command `\textcolor{}{}`?

Here the respective blocks as found on the template on Overleaf:
[image]

Comment: You mean something along the line of `\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=green!80!black}` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just open the `beamercolorthememetropolis.sty` from your TeX distribution (OS search does it for you).

There you would find something like:

```
\definecolor{mLightBrown}{HTML}{EB811B}
\definecolor{mLightGreen}{HTML}{14B03D}
```

and following

```
\setbeamercolor{example text}{%
  fg=mLightGreen
}
```

So you could use `\textcolor{mLightGreen}{Text}`.

[image: example for colors]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Test
    \begin{exampleblock}{Test}
        ASDF
    \end{exampleblock}
    \textcolor{mLightGreen}{\bfseries Test}\\
    \textcolor{mLightGreen}{Test}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you took about [this presentation](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/metropolis-beamer-theme/qzyvdhrntfmr) , you could try to add

```latex
\metroset{block=fill}
```

after using the `block` like that:

```latex
\metroset{block=fill}
\begin{block}{Default}
    Block content.
\end{block}
```